# Can we create a struct of array fields directly?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, if we do

```
 struct('a',1:4)
```

it creates an array of struct... What I wanted is

```
 s = struct('a',[]);
 s.a = 1:4;
```

Can we do so in a single command?

Comment: On `struct('a',1:4)` I get a struct with one field `a: [1 2 3 4]`. (R2015b)

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
s.a = 1:4;
```

Matlab creates a structure automatically, no need for the first line.

To get a **performance difference** between the two versions and also erfan's version (see comment under question) use [timeit](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html):

```
t1 = timeit(@no_preallocation);
t2 = timeit(@no_preallocation2);
t3 = timeit(@preallocation);

function no_preallocation()
    s.a = 1:4;
end

function no_preallocation2()
    s=struct('a',1:4);
end

function preallocation()
    s = struct('a',[]);
    s.a = 1:4;
end
```

I get

```
t1 = 1.3965e-06
t2 = 7.1217e-06
t3 = 7.1223e-06
```

which shows that allocating directly is substantially faster.

However, be aware that **NOT preallocating can lead to weird behaviour**, particularly in scripts, because you are not actually deleting the structure s before you are assigning the field a, meaning that if you had `s` in memory before the assignment, you will keep it and simply overwrite a, which might not be the intended behaviour. So preallocation as suggested by Edric and erfan seems to be best.

Comment: @ihcgeneva In general, my struct may have two fields of array types. So we should do s.a = 1:4; s.b=5:8; I am okay with this. Does this dynamic field adding have any performance issue?

Comment: This isn't a fair test - in the first case, you're only building the array the first time around the loop.

Comment: ... the first test should really be `s = []; s.a = 1:4`. However, that's still 4x quicker than using `struct` on my machine.

Comment: @Edric You can put a `clear s` behind `s.a` and check out the resulting timing. The time difference between the two is still the same, which came as a surprise to me too.

Comment: @Edric Just tried again, you are right, I got my timings wrong, thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: With a single field I am not surprised the direct allocation is the fastest. What happens however when you dynamically add fields? I.e. you add fields `b:z` as well. Which is faster in that case?